# Android- Can not import 9 patch images into project

Tags: android, nine-patch

Hi I am having an issue where I can't import a 9 patch image into android studio. I used the tool on android asset studio to create a 9 patch image, though when I tried to import my pictures by dragging and dropping or manually nothing happens or the image is distorted. I was using android studio 2.2.3 and gradle version 2.2.3, currently I have gone back to studio version 2.0. and gradle version 2.0 but I am still having same issue.

Comment: Welcome! See [mcve] to improve this post and help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I think 9.patch is wrong.

Please. Check your Alpha value.